# Angular 2+ Redirect all non trailing backlash urls to trailing backslash urls

Tags: node.js, angular, http, redirect

In my angular app i have large number of routes and i want a 301 redirect of all non trailing backslash to trailing backslash urls handled from server.ts

what I want is like this

```
app.get('/about', function (req, res, next) {  
  return res.redirect('/about/'); 
});

app.get('/person/john', function (req, res, next) {  
  return res.redirect('/person/john/'); 
});
```

how can i achieve for all urls , how is it possible ? including query parameters

Answer (score 0):

You can write routes like this:

```
export const fooRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '/about', component: AboutComponent
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to do it in Angular.

**The only logical way to do this is on your server settings like IIS, nginx, etc.**

There are some wired ways in the internet that can be done in Angular. but I don't recommend them at all. The only logical way is by server side.

One one them can be found in here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14905#issuecomment-283995900

This one actually removes it. but by understanding the idea, you can Add trailing slash.

Comment: I guess this adds trailing slash but does not create a 301 redirect , the reason why I want 301 is that we had an old website which had trailing slash , so for a point of SEO we need a 301 redirection for non slashe urls